# How to display only certain entries (e.g. Favourites) from an Arraylist of Hashmaps?

Tags: arraylist, hashmap, partial-views, subset

I have defined an ArrayList in my main class where I am loading data from an XML feed and creating various tabs with different activities:

```
static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Example of where I put a map entry into the ArrayList of HashMaps:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {      
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
  Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
  map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
  map.put("lat", "Lat: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "lat"));
  map.put("long", "Long: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "long"));
  map.put("favourite", [lookup of true/false favourite status and insert here]);
  mylist.add(map);
}
```

The first tab is a ListViewActivity and I am successfully able to create the list by referencing the ArrayList in the main class: class.mylist via a List Adapter:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                      ListViewActivity.this,
                      main.mylist, R.layout.list,
                      new String[] { "id", "lat", "long" }, 
                      new int[] { R.id.item_id, R.id.item_lat, R.id.item_long });                   
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Where I am stuck is the following...

I have another tab 'Favourites' where in my FavouriteActivity I would like to display a Listview of only those entries in "mylist" for which the 'favourite' state is TRUE.

In other words, display a subset of mylist based upon a certain condition of each entry in the list.

Is this possible?  I have tried cloning, iterating and who knows what, but I've not been able to figure it out... any suggestions (with some small examples) would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you can do this:

Iterate over your `ArrayList`, for each `HashMap` object iterate over its `keys` like this to match Favourite entries in `Map`:

```
for (Map map : myList) {
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
         If("favourite".equals(key)) {
              // ...
          }
    }
}
```